# Align Spark Buttons Icon to the left?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

- How to align the Spark Buttons Icon to the left ?

/ like the icons to be all 3 pixels from the left /

/ I have checked the sking class of the Spark buttons, but they doesnt expose the Icon property for further extending the skin /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the way - it was just trought the skining of the class. :)